# mysql Database multi cols count

Tags: php, mysql

I have database like this:

```
|1|2|3|
++++++++
|a|h|f|  
|f|d|s|  
|d|f|a|  
|h|a|d|  
|a|d|f|  
|f|f|a|
```

And basically I want count and show result how many times every single record occurs in this table like

```
a=>5  
d=>4  
f=>6
```

Guess I need to use COUNT but no idea how?

Comment: Dear Andreas, from the "how to ask your question section": what did you already try and why didnt it work for you?

Comment: AFAIK, you cant. You will have to make three queries (or maybe a single `UNION`)

Comment: I try: select 1, count(*) from typer_users group by 1

but give me only
Array(
  [1] => 1
    [count(*)] => 65
)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `union all` to "stack" each of the 3 columns into one column, then count:

```
select x, count(*) from (
    select c1 as x from yourtable union all
    select c2 as x from yourtable union all
    select c3 as x from yourtable
    ) d
group by x
```